# Laravel App not running after copying files to plesk server

Tags: php, laravel, iis, plesk

I get this error after running my app:

```
is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Users\Aligator\projects\memebox.api\storage\logs) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/aliqanbari.ir\;C:\Windows\Temp\)
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel caches config files so when you copy the project, you copy system-specific config files. to fix it just delete the contents of the `bootstrap\cache` folder and you'll be ready to go!